# Using python to extract the paragraph from text file and to exclude catalog and title

Tags: python, nltk

I download a paper from website and would like to use NLTK to do topic modeling with complete sentence. Therefore, I try to exclude irrelevant words or not complete sentences in text file. But, I still can't remove those single word.

For example,
[the format in text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98rOa.png)

I only want to get the last sentence. and as the following code is to divide a text into a list of sentence.

```
tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
tokenizer.tokenize(data)
print('\n'.join(tokenizer.tokenize(data)))
```

But, how could I exclude those single words line by line?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using the split method on each line of the text file.

```
file_list = []
file = open('Your Text File.txt', 'r')
for line in file:
    splitted_lines = line.split(' ')
    if len(splitted_lines) > 1 :
        file_list.append(' '.join(splitted_lines))

outfile = ''.join(file_list)
file_out = open('outfile.txt', 'w')
file_out.write(outfile)
```

Comment: you save my day!